# What is the equivalent function of NodeJS Buffer.from in C# .net core?

Tags: c#, node.js, data-conversion

I am trying to convert this Node.js function into a C# function:

```js
function getKey(name, publicKey, privateKey) {
    let key = $ {
        publicKey
    }: $ {
        name
    }: $ {
        (new Date()).getTime()
    }: $ {
        privateKey
    };
    return Buffer.from((key.match(/.{1,4}/g)).map(s => {
        return Buffer.from(s, "binary").toString("base64")
    }).join(""), "binary").toString("base64");
}
```

I can not seem to find the equivalent of the return `Buffer.From` and match for C#.

Comment: I think there is no such generic way as Buffer.from in C# since you have a way stricter type system - or have one at all ;). Maybe check `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`. The GetBytes override exists for all encoding instances - most are statically predefined in the Encoding class. For base64 encode/decode there is `System.Convert.ToBase64String()` and `System.Convert.FromBase64String()`

Comment: ic thanks for the info, how about the key.match() part? is that a regex expression?

Comment: yes, looks like a regex that allows 1-4 characters, no matter which. "/g" means global and tells the regex to not return after the first match.

So basically this regex seems to create a list with strings, each at least 1, maximum 4 characters long. -> string with 14 characters will be split to 3 strings with 4 characters and one with two characters

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  the map with the lambda is chained to an anonymous function. I would assume that it will do that function for every element in the matched set correct? Would it be correct to assume that this just returns an ordered concatenated base64conversions of the mapped elements?

Comment: I'm not an expert in nodejs/js so I can only speak for kotlin/java/c# - in all those languages map is usually used to transform data with a given function. here it looks like it transforms every element that of that regex match to a string using `Buffer.from(s, "binary").toString("base64")` where `s` is a single match entry of the regex.

Comment: okay and i think its concatenated also.  Thank you very much for this.  this helped a lot in understanding the function and come out with an equivalent.

Comment: `map` returnes a list of elements (each element transformed). Afterwards the `join` concats strings and uses `""` as a separator (so just a concatination, yes)
Afterwards this concatenated string is converted to base64 again.

Comment: ah i see, thats amazing, i could never have understood it that way thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

After the above exchange, I was able to convert the function in C#.  Thanks to the amazing advise of @Dominik.  It delivers the same exact result as the NodeJS function except a couple of '=' characters ate the end of the c# result.

```
public static async Task<string> getkey(string name, string publicKey, string privateKey)
        {
            string keyString = $"{publicKey}:{name}:{getEpoch().ToString()}:{privateKey}";
            
            Regex regmap = new Regex(".{1,4}");
            string concat64 = string.Empty;
            var mt = regmap.Matches(keyString);

            foreach(Match m in mt)
            {
                string converted = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m.Value));
                concat64 += converted;
            }

            string finVal = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(concat64));

            return finVal;
        }
```

Comment: You might want to look at `StringBuilder` to replace `concat64 += converted`